# Buck converter shutdown

Tags: dc-dc-converter, buck, protection

I just put together a buck bonverter PCB that I designed and am using the SiC437 from Vishay. [DataSheet](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2687456.pdf?_ga=2.74885906.148417048.1569037735-1328785729.1554141813)

I am using a power supply to control and measure the input supply voltage and current. I am using a multimeter and resistors to measure and control the output current.

I have started testing the performance of the buck converter:

Supply voltage and current: 10 Volts at 0.55 Amps

Output voltage and current: 5 Volts at 1.03 Amps

So far I was happy with the results. I then bumped up the supply voltage to 25 volts and put the same 4.8 ohm load on the output. This time, it seems the buck converter shut down, as it was drawing 0mA. (Its idle current draw was around 16mA). I attached a 24 ohm load to the output at 25 volts and it was functioning correctly.

I am assuming that the buck converter is going into one of its many shutdown protection modes. I touched the buck converter with my finger during operation and had no noticeable temperature difference so I don't think it was a thermal shutdown. I believe that I may have picked the wrong external components and it is going into a shutdown mode.

I have attached the schematic that I have used for the buck converter circuit as well.[image]

Also, is there a better way of being able to test discharge current performance other than twisting a bunch of 24 ohm resistors together and burning my fingers? Thank you!

Edit: Here are the Waveforms taken from my oscilloscope. The first one is when the supply voltage is 8.0 Volts and the load on the output is 3.3 Ohms.

The second is when the supply voltage is 12.0 Volts with the same 3.3 Ohm load.
[image]
[image]

Comment: What's the saturation current of the inductor? Show waveforms.

Comment: @winny the saturation current of the inductor is 14 Amps and I have added the waveforms into the question.

Comment: That’s a lot of voltage ripple! What’s your ESR? Can you put a small resistor in series with the choke and measure (differentially) the inductor current?

Comment: @winny. I put a small 3.3 Ohm resistor in series and at 8.84V supply, for 1.527 amps. When the supply was at 12V (and shutdown) the current was only 2uA. I am using tantalum capacitors with an ESR of 0.4 Ohms. Is this my issue? Should I have used ceramic capacitors for better high-frequency performance?

Comment: Show waveforms. 0.4 ohms is ginormous. How many in parallel?